# Page is showing horizontal scroll bar while using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am designing a page using bootstrap. I am dividing the page using grid system with class col-lg-x . I have divide into two part using the following code .

```
<div class='container'>
  <div class='row'> 
    <div class='col-lg-7'></div>
    <div class='col-lg-5'></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have added content inside the columns and set box-sizing to border box . The page displays an horizontal bar . What I know about bootstrap grid system it divides page into 12 equal columns, So still after making use of grid system i didn't get why the horizontal bar still displays ?

Comment: This may be because the content inside the columns must be greater than the height of the viewport. It has nothing to do with the grid system.

Comment: Can you reproduce the same issue just with the above code?

Comment: Must be something you've put inside the columns as it works fine here: http://www.bootply.com/gp51EVFTeK

Comment: Do you have a live example or a bootply link?

Answer (score -1):

It seems that your CSS code might be overlapping bootstrap CSS. Because both classes `'.col-lg-7'` and `'.col-lg-5'` works well responsively below 1200 pixel... So there is no chance of scroll bar horizontal or vertical.

```
<div class='container'>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-lg-7'>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
    </div>
    <div class='col-lg-5'>
      <p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ShirishDhotre/0amuqd74/